# Overriding GetHashCode with different properties

Tags: c#, overriding

I have this object:

```
public class Foo  {
    public string MyOwnId { get; set; }
    public Guid FooGuid { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

I would like `Equals()` to only care about those with `MyOwnId`, otherwise they are *never* equal. When a `Foo` has a `MyOwnId` I try to use it, otherwise I want to use `FooGuid`.

Since `FooGuid` probably never will be the same, I did something like this:

```
public bool Equals(Foo foo) {
        if (foo== null) return false;
        return MyOwnId.Equals(foo.MyOwnId);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Foo)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash*7) + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyOwnId) ? MyOwnId.GetHashCode() : FooGuid.GetHashCode());
        return hash;
    }
```

Is this a proper way to do what I want? Or do I also need change my `Equals` method so it looks the same like my `GetHashCode`? For e.g:

```
public bool Equals(Foo foo) {
        if (foo == null) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyOwnId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo.MyOwnId)) return false;
        return MyOwnId.Equals(foo.MyOwnId);
    }
```

Comment: If `MyOwnId == null` then `return MyOwnId.Equals(foo.MyOwnId);` will throw an *exception*. Change it to `String.Equals(MyOwnId, foo.MyOwnId)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ok, but how about my other example of Equals? That takes care about null values

Comment: If two instances (say, A and B) are *equal* according to `Equals` they *must* have the *same* hash code. However, `GetHashCode()` depends on `FooGuid` and `Equals` *doesn't* so the rule is *violated*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's see. Your implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is *erroneous*.

Both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` must never throw an exception; the counter example is

```
  Foo A = new Foo();
  Foo B = new Foo() {
    MyOwnId = "bla-bla-bla",
  };

  // Throws an exception
  if (A.Equals(B)) {}
```

If two instances are equal via `Equals` these instances must have the same hash code; the counter example is

```
  Foo A = new Foo() {
    MyOwnId = "",
  };

  Foo B = new Foo() {
    MyOwnId = "",
  };

  if (A.Equals(B)) {
    // Hashcodes must be equal and they are not
    Console.Write(String.Format("{0} != {1}", A.GetHashCode(), B.GetHashCode()));
  }
```

Possible (simplest) implementation

```
// since you've declared Equals(Foo other) let others know via interface implementation
public class Foo: IEquatable<Foo> { 
  public string MyOwnId { get; set; }
  public Guid FooGuid { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

  public bool Equals(Foo other) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
      return true;
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other))
      return false;
    else
      return String.Equals(MyOwnId, other.MyOwnId);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return Equals(obj as Foo); // do not repeat youself: you've got Equals already
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    // String.GetHashCode is good enough, do not re-invent a wheel
    return null == MyOwnId ? 0 : MyOwnId.GetHashCode(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or do I also need change my Equals method so it looks the same like my GetHashCode?

You change your `Equals` to match how you want equality to be resolved. You've done this.

You change your `GetHashCode()` to key on the same information. In this case:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return MyOwnId == null ? 0 : MyOwnId.GetHashCode();
}
```

Incidentally, your `Equals(object)` is a bit overly-complicated. I would use:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  return Equals(obj as Foo);
}
```

This passes handling the case of `obj` being null to the specific `Equals()` (which has to handle it too), deals with `obj` being something that isn't a `Foo` by passing that `Equals()` a null (so false anyway) and passes the handling of the case of `obj` being something derived from `Foo` to the more specific too (which again, has to handle that).

The short-cut on `ReferenceEquals` isn't worth doing here as there's only one field being compared, and its comparison will have the same `ReferenceEquals` shortcut. You don't though handle `foo` being a derived type in the specialised `Foo`. If `Foo` isn't sealed you should include that:

```
public bool Equals(Foo foo)
{
  return (object)foo != null &&
    foo.GetType() == GetType() &&
    MyOwnId.Equals(foo.MyOwnId);
}
```

If `Foo` is sealed then that `GetType()` comparison should be omitted.

If the logic of the `Equals()` was more complicated than this then the likes of:

```
public bool Equals(Foo foo)
{
  if ((object)foo == (object)this)
    return true;
  return (object)foo != null &&
    foo.GetType() == GetType() &&
    // Some more complicated logic here.
}
```

Would indeed be beneficial, but again it should be in the specific overload not the general override.

(Doing a reference-equality check is more beneficial again in `==` overloads, since they have to consider the possibility of both operands being null so they might as well consider that of them both being the same which implicitly includes that case).

Answer (score 0):

A hash function must have the following properties:

- If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two objects do not have to return different values.
- The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method. Note that this is true only for the current execution of an application, and that a different hash code can be returned if the application is run again.
- For the best performance, a hash function should generate an even distribution for all input, including input that is heavily clustered. An implication is that small modifications to object state should result in large modifications to the resulting hash code for best hash table performance.
- Hash functions should be inexpensive to compute.
- The GetHashCode method should not throw exceptions.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx